# Laravel get relation by custom value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Model - User

```
id [999]
name [foo]
```

Model - Post (without User Foreign Key)

```
id [1]
unique_key [USR_00000999]
data [bar]
```

I would like to get all user with related posts (one to many) by using "custom key" value, is this possible with build in eloquent?

I only manage to looping using foreach one by one with

```
Post::query()
->where('unique_key', sprintf('USR_%08d', $user_id))
->count();
```

Comment: No there is no built in ways to define a relation using a DB mutator on the foreign key value to be used, since they handle key indexes only. Even using directly the `HasMany` class, you can't do it `public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $parent, $foreignKey, $localKey)`

Answer (score 0):

That is not built-into Laravel by default... if you want to know why it's because it's not a common thing that everyone does...

BUT, you can use scope query so you don't need to do the `sprintf` everytime...

[Laravel Query Scopes Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

But I want to ask, why wouldn't you just add `user_id` on your post table and just have an Accessors on your post model for generating the unique_key? That would be much easier on my perspective...

[Laravel Accessor Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

UPDATE: (See Comment)

Is it possible to have an empty user_id on Posts table?
then populate it when the user is created?

say you have a posts with key of USR_00000999... and you have a user with an id of 999... when you create that user you'll just have to update all posts with key of USR_00000999 to have a user_id of 999...

Comment: User-Post relationship is for demonstration purpose. Use case for me, when updating Post, it not created from user but a webhook, the user is not defined when record create and not processing that hook on record, so i looking a way to record first, matching after with custom key.